Inconsistent state updates when using onCellEditingStopped in ag-grid
I am using a react admin component, DatagridAg, which under the hood uses ag-grid. I am trying to add some additional functionality to trigger a cell in the row to be updated when the user edits an adjacent cell. What I currently have is working, but it is inconsistent. Sometimes the state updates, sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes the state updates but the state for the cell I am currently editing does not. I'm guessing there is some async behavior issue here but I'm not sure what it could be.
Here is the relevant code for the ag grid component
 <DatagridAG
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        pagination={false}
        enableRangeSelection={true}
        sideBar={true}
        rowSelection={'multiple'}
        onCellEditingStopped={onCellEditingStopped}
        theme={theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'ag-theme-alpine-dark' : 'ag-theme-alpine'}
      />

And here is the code for the onCellEditingStopped function
  const onCellEditingStopped = params => {
    if (params.colDef.field === 'override_cpm') {
      const ratio = params.data.sqad_cpp / params.data.sqad_cpm;
      params.node.setDataValue('override_cpp', params.newValue * ratio);
      // params.node.updateData({
        // ...params.node.data,
        override_cpp: params.newValue * ratio,
      });
    } else if (params.colDef.field === 'override_cpp') {
      const ratio = params.data.sqad_cpm / params.data.sqad_cpp;
      params.node.setDataValue('override_cpm', params.newValue * ratio);
    }
  };


I've tried a number of different solutions, but can't get them to work.
I tried using updateData to update the cell, but again I think there is some async behavior overwriting the update. It flashes the correct value for a moment and then resets to the oldValue.
Anyone have any idea on why I might be getting inconsistent updates?

DatagridAG is a React Admin Enterprise component, which probably means you subscribed to one of the paid plans. All paid plans give you access to the Support Desk, so feel free to ask your question there, they may be able to help!
